# Access Google Secrets Manager from Firebase Function using Python

Tags: python, flutter, firebase, function, dart

Currently developing a flutter app that is hosted on firebase where users login using an email and password (may or may not be associated with google), then I want them to be able to access the service-account for my Google Bigquery. This would allow them to access the API and read data directly from Bigquery. I thought a secure way to store the API key would be to import it into Google Secrets Manager and then use a Firebase Function to access the secret.

Here is my cloud function.

```
from firebase_functions import https_fn
from firebase_admin import initialize_app
import os

initialize_app()

@https_fn.on_request(secrets=['MY_SECRET_NAME'])
def function_name(req):
    my_service_acct = initialize_app(key=os.environ.get('MY_SECRET_NAME'))
    if len(my_service_acct) is None or len(my_service_acct) < 1:
        raise https_fn.HttpsError(code=https_fn.FunctionsErrorCode.INVALID_ARGUMENT,
                                message=('The function is returning a NULL or 0 character string.'))
    if req.auth is None:
        # Throwing an HttpsError so that the client gets the error details.Dinosaursfly10
        raise https_fn.HttpsError(code=https_fn.FunctionsErrorCode.FAILED_PRECONDITION,
                                message="The function must be called while authenticated.")
    return my_service_acct
```

Here is how I am calling it in flutter:

```
  Future<String> getDbCreds() async {
    try {
      final result = await function.httpsCallable('function_name').call();
      return result.data.toString();
    } on FirebaseFunctionsException catch (e) {
      print(e.code);
      print(e.details);
      print(e.message);
      return 'Function Errored';
    }
  }
```

upon calling the function I get the following in the console:

```
internal
null
internal
```

From this [link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable?gen=2nd#python-preview_5), it says I should use the `raise https_fn.HttpsError()` to give me some detailed information for troubleshooting, but that isn't working. Thoughts on why my function call isn't working?